# data files transfer from google cloud storage to azure blob storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage

My org is currently using CLEO as a file transfer tools from gcp storage buckets to azure blob storage, due to high volume and size of files performance is becoming a concern.

I would like to know what are other possible ways for copying data files from gcp buckets to azure blob storage, Azcopy is one option I found out but is that performance efficient, do I need to install it on composer or VM, what kind of security access I need to deal with to get the privileges on azure storage, would that be service account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out Azure Data Factory. A simple Copy activity should be able to handle this: Google Cloud Storage would be the Source and Azure Blob Storage would be the Sink. Use Binary Datasets for fastest performance.

Comment: data factory is native to azure , files will be pushed from GCP to AZURE what are my options there